# How to marshal an object via JAXB without any information about it?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an object `value`, which is of some type, either `@XmlRootElement`-annotated, or not. I want to marshal it into XML:

```
String value1 = "test";
assertEquals("<foo>test</foo>", toXml("foo", value1));
// ...
@XmlRootElement
class Bar {
  public String bar = "test";
}
assertEquals("<foo><bar>test</bar></foo>", toXml("foo", new Bar()));
```

Can I do it with JAXB existing facilities, or I should create some custom analyzer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could leverage JAXBIntrospector to do the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBIntrospector;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object value = "Hello World";
        //Object value = new Bar();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class, Bar.class);
        JAXBIntrospector introspector = jc.createJAXBIntrospector();
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        if(null == introspector.getElementName(value)) {
            JAXBElement jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(new QName("ROOT"), Object.class, value);
            marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
        } else {
            marshaller.marshal(value, System.out);
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Bar {

    }

}
```

With the above code when the JAXBElement is marshalled it will be qualified with an xsi:type attribute corresponding to the appropriate schema type:

```
<ROOT 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Hello World</ROOT>
```

To eliminate the qualification you can simply change the line that creates the JAXBElement to:

```
JAXBElement jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(new QName("ROOT"), value.getClass(), value);
```

This will result in the following XML:

```
<ROOT>Hello World</ROOT>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Maybe you know how to get rid of `xsi:type` attribute? This is what I'm getting for a `String` object: `<phone xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">(239) 555 2390</phone>`

Comment: @Vincenzo I have updated my answer with details on how to eliminate the xsi:type attribute.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan please see this problem :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816798/objectfactory-methods-generated-by-jaxb

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to marshal `value1`, which is a `String`. You can pass `yourObject.getClass()` to the `JAXBElement` constructor, and `value1`:

```
try {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    String value1 = "test";
    JAXBElement jx = new JAXBElement(new QName("foo"), value1.getClass(), value1);
    m.marshal(jx, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works without using `@XmlRootElement`. The result of the code above was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><foo>test</foo>
```

On the other part, this will not work with a `Bar` object: `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: myPackage.Bar is not known to this context`. However, you can get the value from inside `Bar`, and create the `JAXBElement` with that, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, then JAXB does not have sufficient information to marshal it. You would need to wrap it in a `JAXBElement` first.

Could you do some reflective lovin' to find out how to wrap the object in the appropriate `JAXBElement`?

Comment: check out my answer to see how JAXBIntrospector can be used to avoid any reflection calls.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any good generic way of doing it. Here is my generic solution.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class XMLConverter {

    /**
     * Serialize object to XML string
     * @param object object
     * @param <T> type
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> String marshal(T object) {
        try {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            QName qName = new QName(object.getClass().getCanonicalName(), object.getClass().getSimpleName());
            JAXBElement<T> root = new JAXBElement(qName, object.getClass(), object);

            m.marshal(root, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Deserialize XML string back to object
     * @param content XML content
     * @param clasz class
     * @param <T> type
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> T unMarshal(final String content, final Class<T> clasz) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clasz);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            return u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(content)), clasz).getValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the exception
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: wrong namespace if use object.getClass().getCanonicalName()