# ObjectFactory methods generated by jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to make web services but there are two situations I am getting.

There are two types of xsd file 1st one is:

```
  <xsd:element name="signupRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element
  <xsd:element name="signupResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="signup" type="tns:Signup"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:simpleType name="Signup">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Success"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DuplicateEmail"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

in that case jaxb generates signuprequest signupresponse and signup classes so i can easily make services for example in this case:

```
public Signup signupResponse(String name,String mobile);
```

but if I set signupresponse directly like this:

```
<xsd:element name="signupResponse">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Success"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="DuplicateMail"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
```

jaxb only generate sinuprequest class and do not generate signupresponse and signup classes instead it makes entry in ObjectFactory class like this

```
private final static QName _SignupResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.com", "signupResponse");
```

and method is:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.com", name = "signupResponse")
    public JAXBElement<String> createSignupResponse(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_SignupResponse_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
```

so please guide me how to make services for these types of xsd architecture.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 2):

The element `signupResponse` is considered as simple type of `String.class`, for this reason you haven't a Class generates.

If you want generated the enumeration you should change the XSD

```
<xs:element name="signupResponse" type="signupResponse" />
<xs:simpleType name="signupResponse">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Success" />
        <xs:enumeration value="DuplicateMail" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

in order to generate

```
@XmlType(name = "signupResponse")
@XmlEnum
public enum SignupResponse {

    @XmlEnumValue("Success")
    SUCCESS("Success"),
    @XmlEnumValue("DuplicateMail")
    DUPLICATE_MAIL("DuplicateMail");
    private final String value;

    SignupResponse(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static SignupResponse fromValue(String v) {
        for (SignupResponse c: SignupResponse.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

and ObjectFactory

```
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.com", name = "signupResponse")
    public JAXBElement<SignupResponse> createSignupResponse(SignupResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<SignupResponse>(_SignupResponse_QNAME, SignupResponse.class, null, value);
    }
```